# Anaconda3 fails to install Anaconda Navigator, Anaconda Prompt, Jupyter and Spyder

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have been attempting to install Anaconda for about six consecutive hours already, yet for every time, the installation seems to be unsuccessful. For the first few attempts I get the "failed to create menu" error, yet after disabling my Kapersky, Advanced Systemcare Ultimate and IObit Malware Fighter anti-virus programs, I was able to get no errors. Yet shortly before the installation is completed, a dialogue box flashes instantly and when the installation is complete, all I find in the Anaconda3 directory are a bunch of files and .dlls, while there are only python.exe,  pythonw.exe, and Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe. All other .exe files, such as Anaconda Navigator and Anaconda Prompt, do not exist, nor does Jupyter or Spyder. Anaconda3 does not appear in the list of "installed programs" either. I would love to know what is causing such situation. By the way, I have Visual Studio, MinGW and Java Development Kit installed as well. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: It could help if you specify the OS and Anaconda version

Comment: OS: Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Anaconda version: 5.0.1 64-bit version

Comment: it appears you have a partial install of anaconda try reinstalling it with admin privilages